# Does the last hitting time have finite expectation while the stochastic process a.s. converges to another value at some rate?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

Let's say $X_n$ is a stochastic process and converges almost surely to $1$ with $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} n(X_n - 1) = 1$ a.s.

Define the last time this process hits or crosses $0$ as $n_h = \min\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\{n: X_N > 0, \forall N \ge n \}$.

Then $n_h$ is almost surely finite. But does it have finite expectation?

I tend to believe not. But any ideas of a counterexample?

Comment: You're assuming that $X_0 = 0$, right? (Or maybe just requiring that $X_0 \leq 0$?)

Comment: @AaronMontgomery You are right. Sorry I missed that. Let's just assume $X_0 \le 0$ so that it almost surely crosses.

Comment: Any comment on the requirement that $\lim n (X_n - 1) = 1$ a.s.? It's an interesting requirement; I wondered what inspired it.

Comment: Just to specify a rate of almost sure convergence. Finding a counterexample without this rate must be easier but I wonder how to make a counterexample design with some rate restriction.

Comment: The restriction is kind of strange, though -- it precludes counterexamples like a simple random walk on $\mathbb Z$ stopped upon its first visit to $1$ (because then $X_n - 1$ just zeroes out). I think this can still be done even with the restriction (working on an answer now) but I was just trying to figure out if that was really your intent.

Answer (score 0):

The expectation can indeed be infinite.

The best counterexample is probably a simple random walk on $\mathbb Z$ stopped at its first visit to $1$ (call it $X_n$); however, this doesn't quite work, because with probability $1$ this process has $X_n = 1$ identically for sufficiently large $n$; hence, $\lim n (X_n - 1) = 0$. Without that restriction, the counterexample would work, as follows: with probability $1/2$ the walk would take its first step to the left. Conditioning on that event, the time of the *first* return to $0$ has infinite expectation, and the time of *last* visit to $0$ is stochastically larger.

So, we want to extract the good parts of that example while satisfying the convergence condition. We'll do so as follows:
let $X_n$ be a random walk on the states $\{0, -1, -2, \dots\} \cup \{1 - 1/n \colon n \in \mathbb Z_{>1}\}$. We define transition probabilities by:

- For $x < 0$, $p(x, x-1) = p(x, x+1) = 1/2$.
- $p(0, -1) = p(0, 1/2) = 1/2$.
- For $x > 1$, $p(1 - \frac 1 x, 1 - \frac{1}{x+1}) = 1$.

This behaves like a simple random walk on $\mathbb Z$ until the first time the walk moves to the right of $0$; at that point, it moves to $x = 1/2$ and begins a slow drift toward $0$, deterministically moving along the set $\{\frac 1 2, \frac 2 3, \frac 3 4, \dots\}$. The expectation of the time of the last visit to $0$ is still infinite (for the same reasons as the other example); however, this one has the desired property that $\lim |n(X_n - 1)| = 1$, since with probability $1$ there is some $N(\omega)$ such that $X_{N + n} = 1 - \frac 1 n$.

Note that I took some liberties applying absolute values to the convergence rate, since $X_n - 1$ is negative; if you want a counterexample without those, change the states to $\{1 + 1/n\}$, have $p(0, 3/2) = 1/2$, and have the walk drift *down* to $1$ from above.

Comment: Thanks! A neat example. And quite flexible since by the same way we can make counterexamples for an arbitrary convergence rate. Also this is easy to be generalized to continuous state domain, using Brownian bridges to connect positive points and replacing the negative part by Wiener process.

Comment: Sadly I don't have enough reputation to vote for you. Haha.

Comment: Not a problem! Accepting the answer works just fine! :)